# What is the proper syntax for FINDSTR /E in BATCH to match strings that are at the end of a line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm writing a subroutine in Batch that will extract text in the middle of a string, and can accept two sets of characters (like a word or phrase), rather than individual delimiters, as its arguments. In addition, I'd like to get the index position of the first character of the lookup value. The way I'm going to do this is by looping through characters and eliminating it one by one from both sides until the lookup string sets match the beginning and end of the surviving string.

Character elimination is done using variable offset/index like in this one: `!_str:~%_idx%!`, where `_str` is the string to search, and `_idx` is the offset count, then pipe it to `FINDSTR /B` to see if the lookup string matches the beginning characters of the surviving string from the loop. So far, no problem. But when I do the process for the second lookup string to the right side of the string being searched, and piped it to `FINDSTR /E` to see if the second lookup string matches the end of the surviving string from the loop, it doesn't seem to work.

From my understanding from these sources,

- Command Prompt > `FINDSTR /?`
- [FINDSTR](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)

`FINDSTR` switches `/B` and `/E` match lookup strings that are at the beginning and end of a line, respectively.

So, out of desperation, I created some tests with different variations even though I know that these variations are not the issue, but I still did it, anyway. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
title FINDSTR_TEST
echo off
cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_str=Hello World"

echo String to search: %_str%
echo:
echo Matches pattern if at the BEGINNING of a line.
echo 1: & echo %_str% | findstr /b "Hello"
echo 2: & echo %_str% | findstr /b /l "Hello"
echo 3: & echo %_str% | findstr /b /C:"Hello"
echo:
echo:
echo Matches pattern if at the END of a line.
echo 1: & echo %_str% | findstr /e "World"
echo 2: & echo %_str% | findstr /e /l "World"
echo 3: & echo %_str% | findstr /e /C:"World"
echo:
echo ERRORLEVEL: %errorlevel%

pause
endlocal
exit
```

Here's the actual result:

```
String to search: Hello World

Matches pattern if at the BEGINNING of a line.
1:
Hello World
2:
Hello World
3:
Hello World


Matches pattern if at the END of a line.
1:
2:
3:

ERRORLEVEL: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But this is what I was expecting:

```
String to search: Hello World

Matches pattern if at the BEGINNING of a line.
1:
Hello World
2:
Hello World
3:
Hello World


Matches pattern if at the END of a line.
1:
Hello World
2:
Hello World
3:
Hello World

ERRORLEVEL: 1
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Two quick questions here:

1. Is there any problem with my code especially where `/E` switch is being used?
2. Aren't these `/L` and `/C:string` switches redundant? It appears to me that they do the same thing.

Any clarifications on these matter will be appreciated.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: for strings at EOL use either `%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LEC:"String"` or `%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /RC:"String$"`.

Comment: `World` is clearly not at the End of the line, there is whitespace between it and the pipe, i.e. `echo Hello World |`. _If you're testing this without echoing off, you should see it in your output._

Comment: Oh, geez, this is embarrassing. You're right, @Compo. I didn't realized it until you pointed it out. To be honest, I still quite don't understand how piping works. I just take examples from the internet and in most of these examples, the pipe character has leading and trailing spaces. Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a follow up of my comment, you should be able to see exactly what is happening, if you create a three line batch file, exactly like this:

```sh
Echo Hello World | FindStr /B "Hello"
(Echo Hello World) | FindStr /E "World"
@Pause
```

The output will show whitespace, where you didn't specifically add it:

```
C:\Users\SpaghettiCode>Echo Hello World   | FindStr /B "Hello"
Hello World

C:\Users\SpaghettiCode>(Echo Hello World )  | FindStr /E "World"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

My preferred solution, is to use `Set /P` instead of `Echo`, because the output can be specifically terminated using doublequotes, and redirection. For example:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title FINDSTR_TEST
ClS
Set "_str=Hello World"
Echo String to search: %_str%
Echo(
Echo Matches pattern if at the BEGINNING of a line.
Echo 1:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /R "Hello"
Echo 2:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L "Hello"
Echo 3:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /R /C:"Hello"
Echo 4:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^Hello"
Echo 5:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "^Hello\>"
Echo(
Echo(
Echo Matches pattern if at the END of a line.
Echo 1:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /R "World"
Echo 2:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /L "World"
Echo 3:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /E /I /R /C:"World"
Echo 4:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "World$"
Echo 5:& Set /P "=%_str%" 0< NUL | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\<World$"
Echo(
Echo ERRORLEVEL: %ErrorLevel%
Pause
Exit /B
```

As you can see, I added a couple of extra, options to each of the examples, which for me, are probably more useful for your provided example string. You'll also note that I moved your ampersands, after the test numbers, to show you that you were printing `number` `colon` `space`, not `number` `colon`.

Comment: I like your comment on my post, pointing out the space before `|`. So, to make it simpler, the code would have to be edited like this: `echo %_str%|findstr /e /l "World"`.

Comment: As for my second question on my original post: "Aren't these /L and /C:string switches redundant? It appears to me that they do the same thing." Can you comment on that, please?

Comment: I used both in my answer above. No they're not redundant for some things, without knowing your exact requirements, I cannot say, because all of your question is fake content and code. `/L` is a stipulation that all characters are literal, and cannot be used with `/R`, as they're exclusive. `/C` can be used, with `/R` to part literalize, i.e mix some literal stuff with regular expression stuff. My advise is to always use `/L` unless you specifically need pattern/regex matching, and in those cases, you could consider using `/C` with it, where appropriate.

Comment: I got it now. /L to make all strings literal, /C to isolate and apply it only to certain strings. Thanks, man.

Comment: Just to add, for the example you've provided in your question, if you do not need regex, or pattern matching, you could of course use `find.exe` instead, `Echo Hello World | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I "Hello "`, and `Echo Hello World | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I " World"`

Comment: `FINDSTR` is best suited to my script because I need `/B` and `/E` options. If the string to be searched for is `aaa bbbHello Worldxxx yyy`, the first search string is `Hello` and the second search string is `World`, I'm going to eliminate each strings one by one and pipe the surviving string to `FINDSTR /B` and `E` one after the other. If `FINDSTR /B` or `E` finds the search string, the recursive process stops, leaving only `Hello World`.

Comment: I understand what your actual code is trying to do, although I do think you're probably going about it in the wrong way. My comment was mainly for future visitors, because as I've already mentioned, your actual task does not form any part of this test, which is whether `Hello` appears at the beginning of a line, and/or `World` appears at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

As others already pointed out, the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in front of the pipe is output as well and therefore included in the string processed by `findstr`.

However, to safely pass a string over a pipe in general, you should use the following syntax, given that [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is disabled (which is the default setting) and the string is stored in variable `_str`:

```
cmd /V /D /C echo(!_str!| findstr /E /I "world"
```

This enables delayed expansion in the child `cmd` instance (`/V`), so variables are expanded as late as possible, so no special characters can harm. The harmful <kbd>SPACE</kbd> is of course left out here.

The `echo` command would cause the pipe to initiate a new `cmd` instance anyway since `echo` is a `cmd`-internal command, so the overall performance is not degraded.

---

Passing multiple strings by `echo` over a pipe becomes a little bit tricky, because something like:

```
(echo abc&echo def) | …
```

or:

```
(
    echo abc
    echo def
) | …
```

introduces additional <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, which result from the conversion of such command blocks to single command lines and therefore also by replacing line-breaks by ampersands. For example, for the former example, the command echo looks like this:

> ```
> (echo abc  & echo def )  | …
> ```

However, there is a way, namely to include escaped ampersands, which are taken literally:

```
(echo abc^& rem/ & echo def^& rem/) | …
```

or:

```
(
    echo abc^& rem/
    echo def^& rem/
) | …
```

The `rem/` command is just a harmless and ignored remark, and the `/` ensures that subsequent commands are not treated as remarks but are executed as expected.

Of course all this can be combined with `cmd /V /D /C` as shown above.